# Why do variables in the global scope get assigned to the window object?

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = 'bar';
console.log(window.foo); // bar
```

Seems like variables get assigned as properties to `this`, but inside anonymous functions, `this` refers to the parent scope, but doesn't assign variables to the parent scope.

```
function() {
    var foo = 'bar';
}();

window.foo; // undefined
```

**What object do variables get assigned to in non-global scopes?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To cite http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#execution_context:

> Every execution context has a so-called `Variable Object` associated
>   with it. Similarly to execution context, Variable object is an
>   abstract entity, a mechanism to describe variable instantiation. Now,
>   the interesing part is that variables and functions declared in a
>   source text are actually *added as properties of this Variable object*.
>
> When control enters execution context for Global code, a `Global object`
>   is used as a `Variable object`. This is precisely why variables or
>   functions declared globally become properties of a `Global object`

Yet, these `Variable Object`s are not accessible. The only non-internal one is the global object, `window` or `this` (in global context).

The relevant section in the specification is [#10: Executable Code and Execution Contexts](http://es5.github.com/#x10).

Comment: So does the `window` object exist solely to behave as the global `Variable Object`?

Comment: Ecmascript itself does not need a `window` object. *[The global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1) may have additional host defined properties.* For example, the HTML spec defines the [`Window` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-window-object)

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, all variables are assigned to some scope object. However, only the scope object of global variables is accessible in JavaScript in the browser through the `window` object. Variables in a function scope are assigned to some scope object used internally by the JavaScript runtime, but this cannot be accessed by the user.

In another environment, global variables may be accessible as properties of another object (such as `GLOBAL` in [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)) or may be inaccessible (such as application scripts running inside the Windows Script Host).

Comment: Why is the global scope object not internal, or conversely, why can't non-global scope objects be accessed? Seems inconsistent.

Comment: No scope object can *ever* be directly accessed. However any piece of code has access to variables in its own scope, as well as variables in parent scopes. It just happens that the global scope is the parent scope of all other scope objects, which is why it's always available

Comment: @Gareth makes a good point. If we could access all scope objects directly, the garbage collector would have a bad time trying to clean up references. The global scope wraps all other scopes, so it is always available and can only be garbage collected when the script terminates.

Answer (score 0):

They're available only in the function they're declared in.

Function scope is the only other scope in JavaScript, btw, unlike block-scoping in other `{}` languages.)

*Re: your edit* Don't be fooled--JS's `this` semantics are a bit irksome IMO--`this` may not be what you expect under a variety of circumstances.

Comment: Yeah my edit was wrong. Regarding your post: Why are global variables assigned to the window object though?

Comment: @ddlshack Because in a browser context that's just where the global scope is.

Answer (score 0):

Inside self-invoking anonymous function eg:

```
function() {
    ....
}()
```

All variables remain inside it and do not attach themselves to global object or `window`. Using that technique, there are patterns created such as [module/singleton pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

Notice that in JS, variables have **function-level** scope.